# expected css "title" with text in capybara

Tags: rspec, capybara

I am using capybara in place of webrat in rails. I have installed capybara and use gem 'capybara' in Gemfile. when I use

```
page.should have_selector("title", :text => "anything title")
```

it's give an error

```
Failure/Error: page.should have_selector("title", :text => "anything title")
expected css "title" with text "anything title" to return something
```

test file is as below:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Test pages" do  
  describe "Home page" do    
    it "should have the content 'Demo App'" do
    visit '/test_pages/home'      
    page.should have_selector("title", :text => "anything title")               
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried `save_and_open_page` right before your test assertion to see what Capybara thinks it is seeing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not sure which version of gems you are using but I ran into a similar instance where using :text failed but when I used :content it passed the test. I'm using rails 3.2.3, rspec-rails 2.9.0, capybara 1.1.2 and therubyracer gems on Ubuntu Lucid Lynx.

Try replacing

```
page.should have_selector("title", :text => "anything title")
```

with

```
page.should have_selector("title", :content => "anything title")
```

Comment: Hey! I am using gem 'rails', '3.2.3', gem 'rspec-rails', '2.9.0', and also gem 'capybara', '1.1.2' on Ubuntu and as well as windows also. I've used :content and it's working fine! Thanks.

Comment: Glad it worked but I have since gotten :text to work and according to the documentation using :text is the correct way to do this. I had a ghost in the machine as I cannot recreate the issue. See [rubydoc:Capybara::RSpecMatchers#have_selector](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara/RSpecMatchers#have_selector-instance_method)

Comment: I have the same problem. For some reason, only on the title element, `:content` works but `:text` does not... so weird.

Comment: For me a test with :content passed even though it shouldn't have passed.

Comment: It didn't work for me either way. with :context I get the following error:
Failure/Error: page.should have_selector('title',
     ArgumentError:
       invalid keys :content, should be one of :text, :visible, :between, :count, :maximum, :minimum
Is there any other solution for this problem?

Comment: This is an issue with :text in Capybara 2, specifically text which is "invisible" such as that in <head>. Clearly not invisible since it's displayed in the browser title area, but it's not in the page itself either -- thus the bug. See more info here: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/863

Comment: I agree with @DreadPirateShawn. I fixed this issue by adding `:visible => false` to the second parameter. So, in my case, it looks like this: `page.find :xpath, '//title', :visible => false`

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that browsers treat the `<title>` tags as being invisible. (Thank you [DreadPirateShawn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128977/dreadpirateshawn) for linking to the [issue](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/863) on this subject).

There's no 'clean' way to get the title, but with a bit of a hack you can still test the title's value by doing the following:

```
first('head title').native.text.should == "WhateverYourTitleNeedsToBe"
```

Do NOT use the `:content` symbol because in older versions of Capybara invalid tags would be ignored and it would appear as if though your test has passed. The newer version will give you a nice error message like:

> ArgumentError:
>    invalid keys :content, should be one of :text, :visible, :between, :count, :maximum, :minimum

Comment: I believe that the cleanest way to get the title is to use xpath. Like this: `page.find :xpath, '//title', visible: false`

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem, just to let you know, the use of :content is not supported in Capybara, it should be :text.

The problem with :content is that it is not recognized by Capybara and then it is ignored and showed as PASSED, but this is a wrong behavior.

So if you use Capybara, switch every :content to :text to see if the test really passes, maybe there are errors not noticed.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problems. Empirically the following is what I found:

```
page.should have_selector("title", :text => "AnyTitle")
```

will expect your html output to contain a tag as below:

```
<title text="AnyTitle"/>
```

however, if you use :content instead of :text as below

```
page.should have_selector("title", :content => "AnyTitle")
```

then it will expect your html output to contain a tag as below

```
<title>AnyTitle</title>
```

So if your resulting html rendering contains `<title text="AnyTitle"/>` tag, you should use :text
otherwise if your resulting html rendering contains `<title>AnyTitle</title>` tag, you might want to use :content instead.

P.S. my Gem environments:
capybara-2.0.2,
rails-3.2.12,
rspec-rails-2.12.2,
webrat-0.7.3
if remove webrat, then the ":conetnt" key word is unrecognized by Capybara alone.

But the clean way to fix it is:
get rid of webrat and install a stable Capybara-1.1.2, that is in the Gemfile

```
#gem webrat
gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
```

please refer to [prusswan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726316/testing-with-specs-capybara-from-railstutorial-chapter-3-does-not-work-have-se)

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
expect(page).to have_title("some title")
```